# Native/$q Javascript For Loop Promise Resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I think I'm getting closer to understanding Javascript Promises, but there's a new issue with `for` loops. I've got a function that feeds another Spotify URIs, for the second method to retrieve track information and then return to be included in an array. So far I've been finding solutions that use the Bluebird library, but when using AngularJS, integration isn't quite as simple that I can tell.

I'm basically getting back a collection of promises that are not resolved to data.

This is the function in my controller, feeding data to the second function in services:

```
$scope.getUserRecent = function () {
    var id = window.localStorage.getItem('id');
    return UserService.getTracks(id).then(function (data) {
        var tracks = {}, i;

        console.log(data);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tracks[i] = SpotifyService.getTrack(i, data[i].uri, data[i].loved, data[i].from);
            console.log(i + ": " + tracks[i]);
        }
        console.log(tracks);

        return tracks;
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

The function on the other side works absolutely fine, pulling the data down and returning it as it should; the promises, however, are not resolved. How can I fix this?

**Edit:** Access to `$scope.getUserRecent()`:

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    $q.all($scope.getUserRecent()).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.tracks = data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (e) {
    $scope.refresh();
});
```

`UserService.getTracks(id)` returns:

```
[Object, Object]
    0:Object
        from:"string"
        id:1
        loved:true
        sharerId:1
        uri:"6mNMp0g3zkg1K7uBpn07zl"
        __proto__:Object
    1:Object
        from:"string"
        id:2
        loved:true
        sharerId:1
        uri:"14WWzenpaEgQZlqPq2nk4v"
        __proto__:Object
    length:2
    __proto__:Array[0]
```

Comment: Please show what `UserService.getTracks()` returns. Also note that `SpotifyService.getTrack()` will be asynchronous and also you never set any properties of `tracks` object. Also not sure how you use `getUserRecent()`

Comment: Angular has `$q.all` where bluebird has `Promise.all`.

Comment: @charlietfl added some extra detail for you.

Comment: @Bergi do you have an example for proper `$q.all` usage? I'm struggling to understand how it works.

Comment: You'd do `return $q.all(tracks);` - you have to pass in an array of promises

Comment: @Bergi you've saved me a big headache, I had a feeling it was a small problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a consumer function `$scope.refresh` as is you should resolve the promises, then [return a new (different) one](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

**$scope.refresh:**

Same as you wrote.

**$scope.getUserRecent:**

```
function () {
  var id = window.localStorage.getItem('id');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    UserService
      .getTracks(id)
      .then(function (data) {
        var tracks = {}, i;

        console.log(data);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          tracks[i] = SpotifyService.getTrack(i, data[i].uri, data[i].loved, data[i].from);
          console.log(i + ": " + tracks[i]);
        }

        console.log(tracks);

        resolve(tracks);

        })
        .catch(function (error){
          console.error(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    };
```

Some observation in the original OP's `$scope.getUserRecent`:

- Please note that `then` function has no return value, this way you output only `undefined`;
- `return tracks;` written inside the `then` statement returns data only to the calling environment, i.e. `$scope.getUserRecent` and not the outer runtime environment that is the real goal.